# Can't find include headers

Tags: c++, mongodb, cmake

I'm having trouble linking a small mongodb cxx program. Everything appears to me like it should be working but I am sure I haven't done something.

The problem is with mongocxx headers not being found.

I am doing this in cmake with pkg_config

My Project

```
#include <iostream>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{};

    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

    auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    document << "hello" << "world";

    collection.insert_one(document.view());
    auto cursor = collection.find({});

    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

My Cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
set(project "Untitled")
project(${project})

find_package(PkgConfig)
INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

pkg_check_modules(LIBMONGOCXX REQUIRED libmongocxx)
pkg_check_modules(LIBBSONCXX REQUIRED libbsoncxx)

include_directories(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(${project} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${project} ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES} ${LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES} )
```

And pkg-configs output for libmongocxx

```
[sam@localhost ~]$ pkg-config --cflags libmongocxx
-I/usr/local/include/mongocxx/v0.3 -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v0.3 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0
```

These are the correct paths and should link correctly. If I were to change

```
set(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS} /usr/local/include/mongocxx/v0.3)
```

It works but it will then have issues with not finding the library, and so on. I wish I could just use a Makefile but I must use Cmake.

Comment: Have you tried removing the line `INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)` ?

Comment: What's the question? What's the error? What's the value of LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS actually? Poor question.

Comment: My apologies, I should have waited a bit before posting. I was too close to the problem to know exactly what to put down in the question. I just expected everyone to be clairvoyant. I'll take more care next question.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bad question (as usr1234567 pointed out) and the issue was with how I compiled the code for cmake and my mongocxx driver, not with cmake.

I recompiled the code in a fresh vm and with cmake 3.3 it started working.